# Can't setup iCloud account in the People app

Tags: windows-10, icloud, windows-10-v1709

I am trying to add my iCloud account to the People app in Windows 10 (Fall Creator's Edition).

My steps:

1. I start the `People` app and click `Add Accounts`.
2. I select iCloud from the list.  For email address, I enter my login email address for iCloud.  For `Send your messages...`, I enter my name.  And then the iCloud password.  And then click `Sign in`.
3. It says `Your account was setup successfully`, but then when I dismiss the dialog, it says [image].

What am I missing?  Why does it not connect?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using two-factor authentication for your Apple ID you'll have to use an app-specific password.

1. Sign in to your Apple ID account page.
2. In the Security section, click Generate Password below App-Specific Passwords.
3. Follow the steps on your screen.

After you generate your app-specific password, enter or paste it into the password field of the app as you would normally.